# Android: Using the app home page as launcher activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am building a simple facebook login application in android. I am using my login activity as the launcher activity. However, I would like to use my home page as launcher activity if the user is already logged in, otherwise login activity act as the launcher activity. Can anyone tell me the right way to do that?

Comment: And you can not check in Login Activity user authorization. And if it is already authorized, run your Activity? Or create another Activityfor authorization checking.

Answer (score 1):

If the user login, save that data, could be a string value, int, boolean, etc... check the data and if matches, make a staractivity intent.

Use my library to achieve that: [KeySaver](https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver)

In your Login Button (onClickListener) make this:

```
mLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!KeySaver.isExist(this, "haslogin")){
                    KeySaver.saveShare(this, "haslogin", true);
            }
        });
```

And at the very beginning of your Login Activity make this:

```
    if(KeySaver.isExist(this, "haslogin")){
          Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
          startActivity(myIntent);
    }else{
        // do your code for login, etc
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When logging in first time do this:

```
SharedPreferences shared;
shared=getSharedPreferences("com.example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
shared.edit().putBoolean("loggedin",true).apply();
```

After you are already logged in

in Your onCreate() of loginActivity do this:

```
SharedPreferences shared;
shared=getSharedPreferences("com.example", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if(shared.getBoolean("loggedin",false)){
startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Homepage.class));
finish();
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply, but now i am not able to go back to my login activity to logout and login as a new user. Please let me know how to log out using the above mention method